# Синхронизация потоков в приложении с асинхронным кодом

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Искал удобный вариант обертывания семафора для создания простого примитива синхронизации, который можно использовать вместе с async/wait. Сделал вариант с использованием ключевого слова using:

```
public class AsyncLock:Idisposable
{
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

  public AsyncLock()
  {
      _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim (1,1);
  }

  public async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync()
  {
     await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     return this;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
      _semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Использую так:

```
var locker=new AsyncLock();
using(await locker.LockAsync())
{
   //Некоторая операция, требующая синхронизации
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я AsyncLock использую как член класса, иными словами - многократно в рамках какого-либо модуля, автоматический вызов Dispose может привести к зачистке ресурсов - уничтожению AsyncLock экземпляра, что, само собой, приведет к null-reference исключению?

Comment: Спасибо, если оформите в качестве ответа, я его приму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов `Dispose` не приводит к удалению объекта, если у вас `AsyncLock` будет объявлен как член класса, например:

```
class Parent
{
    private AsyncLock locker;
    // ...
    public async Task<int> Bar()
    {
          using(await locker.LockAsync())
          {
             //Некоторая операция, требующая синхронизации
          }

          // тут locker удален из памяти не будет
    }
}
```

то он тудет оставаться в памяни (!= null) до тех пор, пока родительский обхект не будет удален (или явно присвоено null), т.к. на него все равно остается ссылка и GC его не удалит.

Comment: @rdorn нет не будет, т.к. в приведенном автором примере `Dispose` у `Semaphore` не вызывается, а просто `Release` соответсвенно объект остается в рабочем состоянии и никаких исключений он бросать не будет

Comment: Ок, перепроверил.